# custom cluster theme when high quantities of objects

Tags: here-api

Based on Example
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/clustering/custom-cluster-theme

loaded with 15000 objects from the json file.

The cluster is created by default 2 seconds, and drawn on the map. The custom cluster theme creates a cluster of long and sent many requests:

http://savepic.su/5817768.png

I think that the use of a user cluster in large volumes of data is not possible, is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this should be an issue, unless there there are lot of event listeners created which are not disposed of. Can you share an example where you face the issue ?

I think the issue is caused by creating a lot of H.map.Icon in the custom theme, you basically need only 4 Icons which can be reused. Create something like follows with a global array  clusterMarkers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
            var diameter = 50;          
            switch( i ){
                   case 0 : 
                        diameter = 50;
                        break;  
                   case 1: 
                        diameter = 20;
                        break;
                     case 2: 
                        diameter = 12;
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        diameter = 10;
                        break;
            };


            var clusterMarker = new H.map.Icon(
                    clusterSvg

                    , {
                    size: {w: diameter, h: diameter},
                    anchor: {x: diameter/2, y: diameter/2}
                    }
                  );
            clusterMarkers[i]=clusterMarker;
        }
```

then in the theme

```
 switch( weight ){
        case weight < 10: 
            i=3;
            break;
     case weight < 100: 
            i=2;
            break;
      case weight < 1000: 
            i=1;
            break;
      case weight < 10000: 
            i=0;
            break;  
     };

    var clusterMarker = new H.map.Marker(cluster.getPosition(), {
        min: cluster.getMinZoom(),
        max : cluster.getMaxZoom(),
        icon: clusterMarkers[i],
      });
```

Comment: Thanks! In the same way the show remade markers objects now all is well.

Comment: If use custom cluster theme, how to show the weight of each cluster?